# Upload files via FTP - Safety

Tags: php, mysql, ftp

I am working on a website that any member can upload photo for sharing, etc. I am planning to keep the file names in MySQL database and physical file at FTP server which means members will have access to FTP server indirectly. (I keep the FTP, MySQL username and password in config file which is not in the root directory) I created two users for MySQL database one has full access for me the other one which has given in config file for members has restricted access. So I feel safe about my MySQL account.

On the other hand, I am not experienced about FTP accesses. I understand that I can have only one FTP user for one domain and can't restrict access. I do not feel comfortable about giving that information at config file. What should be the normal, safer procedure for members file uploads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is almost always a bad idea to give users FTP access to your server. You can have more than one ftp user per domain, and you can restrict user access to FTP with password or firewall. Why not upload images through html form ? This is how its normally done.

Comment: Can you explain a little more uploading through html form? I am using html form and php but in the end I need ftp name and password to access server?

Comment: Take a look here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp. You pretty much manage file uploads with html and php.  Your users upload files through a web form. Your php script catches them and saves them wherever you want on the server side. This way your php script can tell the sql database where the file resides, what name it has etc.( because the php script is the one handling it on the server side).  You should use your FTP only to maintain the website, as an administrator (to put your website on the web server). You should not let your users have ftp access.

Comment: thanks a lot... I always thought that example directories inside the move_uploaded_file function is a local directory. I give a shot and worked... I did not even think that there may be a possibility of uploading a file to server without a password:) I do not have enough reputation to vote up.. sorry for that...